# IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-4, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

Please find the error below:
Java version : 1.8.0_101

> 2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:110 - Adding [servletConfigInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:110 - Adding [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:110 - Adding [jndiProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:110 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:110 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:126 - Initialized StandardServletEnvironment with PropertySources [servletConfigInitParams,servletContextInitParams,jndiProperties,systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardServletEnvironment:175 - Replacing [servletContextInitParams] PropertySource with [servletContextInitParams]
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:513 - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 19 17:17:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:110 - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:110 - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 DEBUG StandardEnvironment:126 - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
>   2016-10-19 17:17:56 INFO  XmlBeanDefinitionReader:316 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]
>
> **2016-10-19 17:17:56 ERROR ContextLoader:331 - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:343)**
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:303)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:216)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:187)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:540)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:454)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4715)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5179)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:586)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1452)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at **org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>           at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:329)
>           ... 63 more
>   19-Oct-2016 17:17:57.166 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file**
>   19-Oct-2016 17:17:57.172 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/FACTNoXMLDemo] startup failed due to previous errors
>   2016-10-19 17:17:57 INFO  XmlWebApplicationContext:873 - Closing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 19 17:17:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   **2016-10-19 17:17:57 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext:883 - Exception thrown from ApplicationListener handling ContextClosedEvent
>           java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 19 17:17:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy**
>
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:346)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:333)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:880)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4762)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:586)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1452)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> 2016-10-19 17:17:57 WARN  XmlWebApplicationContext:891 - Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Oct 19 17:17:56 CDT 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:359)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:888)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:841)**
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.closeWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:579)
>           at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:115)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4762)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5401)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:473)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:285)
>           at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:136)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>           at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:586)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1452)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   19-Oct-2016 17:17:57.708 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\Softwares\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M10\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M10\webapps\APPNoXMLDemo.war has finished in 5,319 ms

Please find the code below: Im using Spring4 annotation loading +Hibernate+Spring Rest, im not able to load applicaiton. Server :Tomcat 7 , tried with version 9 also.

```html
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.comp.fact.configuration")
public class APPConfiguration {
 
 @Bean
 public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
  InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
  viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
  viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
  viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

  return viewResolver;
 }

}
```

```html
public class APPInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
 @Override
 public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

  AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
  ctx.register(APPConfiguration.class);
  ctx.setServletContext(container);

  ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
    "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

  // The following line is required to avoid having jersey-spring3 registering it's own Spring root context.
// i have tried by addin this also.
  //container.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "");

  servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
  servlet.addMapping("/");
 }

}
```

```html
@Controller
public class LoginValidationController extends HttpServlet {

 /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 
 @Autowired
 LabelDAOImpl labelDAOImpl;
 
 @RequestMapping("/login")
 public ModelAndView homePage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 {
  System.out.println("inside login controller");
  String username = request.getParameter("userkey");
  String password  = request.getParameter("userpassword");
  BarCode1D barCode1D =new BarCode1D();
  labelDAOImpl.saveBarcode1DData(barCode1D);
  //if (username.equals("ravi") && password.equals("ravi")) {
   return new ModelAndView("dashboardHome");
  //} else {
   //return new ModelAndView("index");
  //}
  
 }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class LabelDAOImpl implements LabelDAO {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LabelDAOImpl.class);

    public LabelDAOImpl() {
    }

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    /**
     * @return the sessionFactory
     */
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param sessionFactory
     *            the sessionFactory to set
     */
    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    public LabelDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
 xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.comp.app</groupId>
 <artifactId>APPNoXMLDemo</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
 <name>APPNoXMLDemo</name>

 <properties>
  <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
  <jersey.version>2.23.1</jersey.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
   <version>${springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
   <version>${springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
   <version>${springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
   <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <!--<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.1</version>
  </dependency> -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
   <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle/classes12 -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
   <artifactId>classes12</artifactId>
   <version>10.2.0.2.0</version>
   <scope>system</scope>
   <systemPath>C:\sampleApps\Spring4MVCHelloWorldNoXMLDemo\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\lib\classes12.jar</systemPath>
  </dependency>

  <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-spring3</artifactId> 
   <version>${jersey.version}</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
   <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
   <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId> </exclusion> <exclusion> <artifactId>bean-validator</artifactId> 
   <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions> 
   </dependency> -->
   <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
     <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
     <version>2.6.2</version>
</dependency>
  <!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.6.3</version>
  </dependency> -->
  <!-- <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
 <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
 <version>1.9.13</version>
 </dependency> -->
  <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId> <artifactId>jettison</artifactId> 
   <version>1.1</version> </dependency> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload 
   <dependency> <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId> <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId> 
   <version>1.3.2</version> </dependency> -->
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-bundle -->
  <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId> 
   <version>1.11</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId> 
   <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId> <version>1.19.2</version> </dependency> -->

 </dependencies>
```

Comment: Show your applicationContext and web.xml

Comment: Here im loading using WebApplicationInitializer and beans are autowiring.
Please find the above code for spring initialization.

Comment: Please let me know found any solution to this.